# scrolling issue of uitableview and web view

Tags: iphone, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview, ios4

I have a grouped table view which consists of custom cells.

The problem is that when i scroll to the last cell and footer, its not holding to the view. I mean when i drag the table upwards i can see the last row and footer but when i release the finger the tab bar is hiding the last cell and the footer and the table view is bouncing back to show last but one row.

The same applies to the webview. I can see the entire content when i drag but its not holding up to the content that is at the end of the webview. Hope i am clear...

Can anyone plz help me fixing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have the header and footer enabled in the xib file (assuming you have one).

Also make sure that your custom cells are returning their size properly by using the following UITableViewDelegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```